# Troubles installing Sybase ASE ODBC Driver on windows 7

Tags: odbc, sap-ase

Below are the steps followed to load Sybase ASE ODBC Driver on Windows 7:

1. Tried to run the exe file `odbcad32.exe` from directory `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`
2. Gave the network address on `ODBC Sybase ASE Driver Setup` page and clicked on `TestConnect` button. `Logon to Sybase ASE` window opened.
3. When I gave the login details on the `Logon to Sybase ASE` window, the following warning message popped up:

> [MERANT][ODBC Sybase ASE driver]
>
> Unable to load communication module. Netlib Driver has not been correctly installed.

If anyone has faced such issue and know the resolution, please help.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like the old MERANT driver was incompletely or incorrectly installed.

You could try a driver from a different vendor, like [my employer](http://www.openlinksw.com/)'s [Single-Tier "Lite" Edition ODBC Driver for Sybase & Microsoft SQL Server](http://uda.openlinksw.com/odbc-sqlserver-st/).  (The same driver supports connections to all versions of Microsoft SQL Server and Sybase ASE, and most versions of SQL Anywhere/Sybase ASA.)  This driver has no external dependencies, and both 32-bit and 64-bit variants have been proven to work on Windows 7.